# No puedo editar en mi Gridview "Sintaxis incorrecta cerda de 'nvarchar'

Tags: sql-server, html5, asp.net

Contexto: Estoy tratando de realizar un edit en mi gridview (gridview libros) y al momento de dar al botón actualizar me manda este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código de gridview

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="1406px" Height="5px">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridLibros" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" CssClass="gridview" Style="margin-left:400px" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   CellPadding="0" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Horizontal" PageSize="5" Width="50%" Height="270px" HorizontalAlign="Center" CellSpacing="1" OnRowUpdating="Actualizar_Libros">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Codigo">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCodigo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Codigo") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Titulo" SortExpression="Titulo">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitulo" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Bind("Titulo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Titulo") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Editorial" SortExpression="Editorial">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditorial" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Bind("Editorial") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Editorial") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Autor" SortExpression="Autor">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAutor" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Bind("Autor") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Autor") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ubicación" SortExpression="Ubicación">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUbicacion" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Bind("Ubicacion") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Ubicacion") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ultimo Lector" SortExpression="Ultimo Lector">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUltlec" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Bind("[Ultimo Lector]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Ultimo Lector]") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Disponible" SortExpression="Disponible">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDispon" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Bind("Disponible") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Disponible") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fecha Prestamo" SortExpression="Fecha Prestamo">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtprest" runat="server"  MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Eval("[Fecha Prestamo]","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Fecha Prestamo]", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Fecha Devolución" SortExpression="Fecha Devolución">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdev"  runat="server" MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Eval("[Fecha Devolucion]","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl13" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("[Fecha Devolucion]","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" Height="30px"/>

        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"  />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White"/>
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" Height="30px"/>

    </asp:GridView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CadenaConexion %>" SelectCommand="SELECT CODLIB AS Codigo, TITLIB AS Titulo, EDILIB AS Editorial, AUTLIB AS Autor, UBILIB AS Ubicacion, ULTLEC AS [Ultimo Lector], DISPON AS Disponible, CONVERT (DATE, FECPRE) AS [Fecha Prestamo], CONVERT (DATE, FECDEV) AS [Fecha Devolucion] FROM EJEMPLAR ORDER BY Codigo DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Panel>
```

Mi clase que actualiza

```
    protected void Actualizar_Libros(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Label Codigo = (Label)GridLibros.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("lblCodigo");
            TextBox Titulo = (TextBox)GridLibros.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtTitulo");
            TextBox Editorial = (TextBox)GridLibros.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtEditorial");
            TextBox Autor = (TextBox)GridLibros.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtAutor");
            TextBox Ubicacion = (TextBox)GridLibros.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtUbicacion");
            TextBox Ultimo = (TextBox)GridLibros.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("txtUltlec");
            TextBox Dispon = (TextBox)GridLibros.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("txtDispon");
            TextBox Prest = (TextBox)GridLibros.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("txtprest");
            TextBox Devol = (TextBox)GridLibros.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].FindControl("txtdev");

            string SqlQuery = "UPDATE EJEMPLAR SET TITLIB ='" + Titulo.Text.Trim() 
                + "', EDILIB = '" + Editorial.Text.Trim() + "', AUTLIB = '" + Autor.Text.Trim() 
                + "', UBILIB = '" + Ubicacion.Text.Trim() + "', ULTLEC = '" + Ultimo.Text.Trim() 
                + "', DISPON = '" + Dispon.Text.Trim() + "', FECPRE = '" + Prest.Text.Trim() 
                + "', FECDEV = '" + Devol.Text.Trim() + "' WHERE CODLIB = " + Codigo.Text.Trim();
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = SqlQuery;
            GridLibros.DataBind();
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            throw;
        }
      
    }
```

Como es el grid:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Realizo un slqquery para ver como esta llevando la información y esta todo correcto, las comillas simples, las comas, el contenido alojado en cada variable, todo bien, pero no actualiza y me arroja el error de la primera imagen, AYUDA!

Como dato adicional estoy trabajando con VisualStudio 2012 y Sql Management Studio 18

Comment: Probablemente es que el filtro del `WHERE` titne que estar entre comillas simples: `+ "' WHERE CODLIB = '" + Codigo.Text.Trim() + "'"`

Comment: Puse las comillas en el WHERE y sigue apareciendo el error

Comment: Pon el punto de interrupción aquí `SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = SqlQuery;`, y nos copias y pegas el valor de `SqlQuery`  como parte de tu pregunta, por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes corregir la consulta sql que llena el grid y evitar usar corchetes y espacios en los nombres de los campos/columnas y/o alias.

Por ejemplo, uno de tus campos podría quedar como "ultimoLector" (sin espacios) o bien "Ultimo_Lector", pero no con acentos ni espacios, pues por alguna razón al usarlos en los ItemTemplate aparece este tipo de errores.

Comment: Solucionado, Gracias Erick maquinola